# Java Project: Having issues with string tokenizer

Tags: java, project, stringtokenizer

```
This is what I have so far:



     //class to calculate grades

    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    public class Grades {

//variables
private String studentName;
private int studentId;
private double[] quizGrade;
private double[] homeworkGrade;
private double[] labGrade;
private double[] testGrade;
private double projectGrade;

//no args constructor
public Grades(){
    studentName = "";
    studentId = 0;
    quizGrade[16] = 0.0;
    homeworkGrade[10] = 0.0;
    labGrade[7] = 0.0;
    testGrade[3] = 0.0;
    projectGrade = 0.0;     
}

//parameter constructor
public Grades(String name, int id, double[] quiz, double[] homework, 
        double[] lab, double[] test, double project){
    studentName = name;
    studentId = id;
    quizGrade = quiz;
    homeworkGrade = homework;
    labGrade = lab;
    testGrade = test;
    projectGrade = project;
}

//mutator methods
public void setName(String name){
    studentName = name;
}

public void setId(int id){
    studentId = id;
}

public void setQuiz(double[] quiz){
    for(int i = 0; i < quizGrade.length; i++){
        quizGrade[i] = quiz[i];
    }
}

public void setHomework(double[] homework){
    for(int i = 0; i < homeworkGrade.length; i++){
        homeworkGrade[i] = homework[i];
    }
}

public void setLab(double[] lab){
    for(int i = 0; i < labGrade.length; i++){
        labGrade[i] = lab[i];
    }
}

public void setTest(double[] test){
    for(int i = 0; i < testGrade.length; i++){
        testGrade[i] = test[i];
    }
}

public void setProject(double project){
    projectGrade = project;
}

//accessor methods
public String getStudentName(){
    return studentName;
}

public int getStudentId(){
    return studentId;
}

public double getQuiz(){
    return quizGrade[15];
}

public double getHomework(){
    return homeworkGrade[10];
}

public double getLab(){
    return labGrade[7];
}

public double getTest(){
    return testGrade[3];
}

public double getProject(){
    return projectGrade;
}
```

However, here is part of the project that I dont understand:
Note: the input of scores entered from the keyboard should be read as a String then pass that string to the constructor and in the constructor, use split (the method of String) or StringTokenizer to split the scores out the place these values to the elements of quiz array. Do the same for other assignments.

All input will be handled by the controlling class, I just dont understand how to set up a string tokenizer constructor or how to get it to convert a string into a double[].

If I could get some help to just set up one of the variables to do it, say quizGrade, Im sure I could figure out how to set up the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help. If not, leave a comment and we can go from there.

```
String scores = "96.54 45.4 100";
String[] split = scores.split(" ");
double[] dblScores = new double[split.length];
for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    dblScores[i] = Double.valueOf(split[i]);
}
```

The user input (scores) is split, based on a space into an array of Strings. An array of doubles is initialized, since now we know how many there are. Then use Double.valueOf(String) to parse each into the new array. Note: This will throw a NumberFormatException if its not a valid double.

Comment: i need to be able to set up a constructor for it like this though:public quiz(String[] split){
  quizGrade = split;
 } but I cant convert a String to a String[]

Comment: If you need a constructor to accept a String array, you can do this:  Quiz theQuiz = new quiz(scores.split(" ")); It passes a split array of Strings to the constructor.